# Accessing Mainframe on Linux via an Emulator

Tags: mainframe

Can anyone please provide a detailed process of installing an Emulator on Linux and accessing the Mainframe from it. I have gone through almost all on net and I am unable to get through it.

Comment: Why doesn't your company provide an emulator and instructions on use?

Comment: We need more details - are you hoping just to install an mainframe emulator and use it to run software or are you trying to install a  mainframe terminal emulator and access any mainframe you can find, or are you trying to access a specific mainframe? Do the administrators of this mainframe know you are trying to access it? An internet search for 'mainframe emulator Linux' provides useful links for both scenarios.

Comment: I am a participant of Master the Mainframe Competition. A soon as I registered I started searching out for stuff I needed to access ISPF from Linux. The next day I got the mail from IBM, answering all the queries and everything. Thanks a lot @SteveIves for showing such concern.

Answer (score 1):

There are very few 3270 emulators for Linux, including vendor products. The most common one is x3270 which you can install using the standard package installers. For example, sudo apt-get install x3270 on an Ubuntu system.

Comment: ok, I run the Above udo apt-get install x3270, and the package was installed, but unable to find the location of installed file or the program Initiator, please help

Answer (score 0):

Try the MVS turnkey system: http://www.bsp-gmbh.com/turnkey/
I also had issues trying to do it "from scratch" but turnkey sets it all up nicely.